# Determine velocity template request body property type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, velocity

I have an API Gateway that uses velocity templates as a thin wrapper to allow users to do CRUD operations on a DynamoDB table.

I'm trying to write the update operation as dynamically as possible, but where I'm stuck is with determining type from the request body's properties from within the velocity template. This is what I'm working with:

```
#set($body = $input.path('$'))
#set($updateExpression = "set")
#set($expressionAttributeNames = "")
#set($expressionAttributeValues = "")
#foreach($attrName in $body.keySet())
    #set($updateExpression = "${updateExpression} #$attrName = :${attrName},")
    #set($expressionAttributeNames = "${expressionAttributeNames}""#${attrName}"":""${attrName}""")
    #set($attrValue = $input.json("$.${attrName}"))

     #if($attrValue.matches("^-?\\d+$"))
         #set($attrValue = """:${attrName}"": { ""N"": ${attrValue}, ")
     #else
        #set($attrValue = """:${attrName}"": { ""S"": """ + $util.escapeJavaScript($attrValue) + """ },")
     #end

    #set($expressionAttributeValues = "${expressionAttributeValues} ${attrValue}")
    #if($foreach.hasNext)
        #set($expressionAttributeNames = "${expressionAttributeNames}, ")
    #end
#end
{
    "TableName": "TABLE",
    "Key": { "id": { "S": "$input.params('id')" } },
    "UpdateExpression": "${updateExpression} updatedOn = :updatedOn",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {$expressionAttributeNames},
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        $expressionAttributeValues
        ":updatedOn": { "N": "$context.requestTimeEpoch" }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** This would be a sample request body:

`https://api/v1/endpoint/123`

```
{
    "location": {
        "lat": 42,
        "lon": -71
    },
    "rating": 4
}
```

This is the current transformation I get:

```
{
    "TableName": "users",
    "Key": { "gcn": { "S": "123" } },
    "UpdateExpression": "set #number = :number, #location = :location, updatedOn = :updatedOn",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {"#number":"number", "#location":"location"},
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
         ":number": { "S": "1" }, ":location": { "S": "{\"lat\":26.89199858375187,\"lon\":75.77141155196833}" },
         ":updatedOn": { "N": "" }
    }
}
```

I currently just have a test for checking if a value is a number...and it isn't working.

Comment: Please tell us what happens, otherwise we can't help much. For instance, what is generated? Please note that you can add debugging displays at every step to debug your Velocity code.

Comment: @ClaudeBrisson - I hope I added more clarity. I posted my current velocity template and the condition I'm checking. My issue is...I really don't know how I can check if a particular property coming in from my JSON request body is a number, or string, or object, etc.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more digging I reached what I set out for. I have a dynamic Velocity Template mapping for AWS API Gateway for the purpose of updating DynamoDB items.

So far it supports strings, numbers, booleans, and string-escaped objects, as that's how my project stores them (they are not query-able). `ExpressionAttributeNames` exists in case you use a reserved keyword for an attribute name...like I did for 'location'.

If anyone has any improvements/enhancements please let me know, it's a beast of a script.

```
#set($body = $input.path('$'))
#set($updateExpression = "set")
#set($expressionAttributeNames = "")
#set($expressionAttributeValues = "")
#foreach($attrName in $body.keySet())
    #set($updateExpression = "${updateExpression} #$attrName = :${attrName},")
    #set($expressionAttributeNames =     "${expressionAttributeNames}""#${attrName}"":""${attrName}""")
    #set($attrValue = $input.json("$.${attrName}"))

    #if($attrValue.toString().matches("[+-]?\d+"))
        #set($attrValue = """:${attrName}"": { ""N"": ""${attrValue}"" }, ")
    #elseif($attrValue.toString() == "true" || $attrValue.toString() == "false")
        #set($attrValue = """:${attrName}"": { ""BOOL"": ${attrValue} }, ")
    #elseif(($attrValue.toString().startsWith("{") && $attrValue.toString().endsWith("}")) ||
        ($attrValue.toString().startsWith("[") && $attrValue.toString().endsWith("]")) )
        #set($attrValue = """:${attrName}"": { ""S"": """ + $util.escapeJavaScript($attrValue) + """ },")
    #else
        #set($attrValue = """:${attrName}"": { ""S"": " + $attrValue + " },")
    #end

    #set($expressionAttributeValues = "${expressionAttributeValues} ${attrValue}")
    #if($foreach.hasNext)
        #set($expressionAttributeNames = "${expressionAttributeNames}, ")
    #end
#end
{
    "TableName": "", ## Insert your table here.
    "Key": { "gcn": { "S": "$input.params('')" } }, ## Insert your key expression here.
    ## Update below if `updatedOn` is not your audit attribute.
    "UpdateExpression": "${updateExpression} updatedOn = :updatedOn",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {$expressionAttributeNames},
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        $expressionAttributeValues
        ":updatedOn": { "N": "$context.requestTimeEpoch.toString()" }
    }
}
```

**Sample Request Body:**

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "isActive": true,
    "_status": 1
}
```

**Sample Transformation:**

```
{
  "TableName": "users",
  "Key": {
       "id": {
           "S": "1"
        }
  },
  "UpdateExpression": "set #firstName = :firstName, #isActive = :isActive, #_status = :_status, updatedOn = :updatedOn",
  "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
    "#firstName": "firstName",
    "#isActive": "isActive",
    "#_status": "_status"
  },
  "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":firstName": {
      "S": "John"
    },
    ":isActive": {
      "BOOL": true
    },
    ":_status": {
      "N": "1"
    },
    ":updatedOn": {
      "N": "123456789"
    }
  }
}
```